# ¿Porque no me cargan los estilos cuando uso MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

¡Hola!,resulta que no me cargan los estilos cuando estoy cargando otra vista, soy nuevo en mvc y no comprendo el error de esto, pero al ver la direccion no me indica directamente a la ruta correcta pero en el index(controlador frontal principal) no hay problema :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url ?>assets/css/styles.css">
```

Uso de esta forma para dar referencia a mi direccion para los estilos , mis parameters los tengo asi :

```
define("base_url", "http://localhost/mvc-crud/");
define("controller_default", "usuarioController");
define("action_default", "index");
```

En mi controlador frontal que tengo por default cargar el controlador de productoController me carga el metodo index en el cual tiene una require_once de la vista,Esta me carga la direccion sin problema,pero al intentar con otras paginas no me deja , si no que me indica la siguiente ruta :

`http://localhost/mvc-crud/usuario/assets/css/styles.css` ,aqui me produce un error ya que carga primeramente el "usuario", que da referencia a usuarioController,en mi controlador frontal lo tengo normal al cargar la vista :

`http://localhost/mvc-crud/assets/css/styles.css`

Imagen de mi vista principal(sin errores) :

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MVC CRUD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url ?>assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--FORM-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">

            <form action="<?php base_url ?>usuario/login" method="POST">

                <h2>Inicio de Sesion</h2>

                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">Correo:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION["error_login"])) : ?>
                    <p><?php echo $_SESSION["error_login"] ?></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php Utils::deleteSesion("error_login"); ?>


            </form>
            <a href="<?php base_url ?>usuario/register">Registate aquí!</a>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Y la vista que me genera problemas al igual que las otras ya que no me cargan los estilos:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MVC CRUDD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url ?>assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--FORM-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">

            <form action="<?php base_url ?>usuario/register" method="POST">

                <h2>Registro de usuario</h2>

                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">Apellidos:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">Direccion:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">ciudad:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">telefono:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">correo:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <label for="nombre">password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Registrarse">
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION["error_login"])) : ?>
                    <p><?php echo $_SESSION["error_login"] ?></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php Utils::deleteSesion("error_login"); ?>


            </form>
            <a href="<?php base_url ?>">Volver!</a>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

De antemano muchas gracias!, si no quedo claro,estaré atento a los comentarios!

Por si se necesita mas info (controlador frontal) :

```php
<?php
session_start();
require_once "autoload.php";
require_once "config/db.php";
require_once "config/parameters.php";
require_once "helpers/utils.php";


function showError()
{
    $error = new errorController();
    $error->index();
}

if (isset($_GET["controller"])) {
    $nombre_controlador = $_GET["controller"] . "Controller";
} else if (!isset($_GET["controller"]) && !isset($_GET["action"])) {
    $nombre_controlador = controller_default;
} else {
    showError();
    die();
}

if (class_exists($nombre_controlador)) {
    $controlador = new $nombre_controlador();
    if (isset($_GET["action"]) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET["action"])) {
        $action = $_GET["action"];
        $controlador->$action();
    } else if (!isset($_GET["controller"]) && !isset($_GET["action"])) {
        $action = action_default;
        $controlador->$action();
    } else {
        showError();
    }
} else {
    showError();
}
```

edit:

```php
define("base_url", "http://localhost/mvc-crud/");
define("controller_default", "usuarioController");
define("action_default", "index");
```

El contenido de mi .htaccess :

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar rewrite
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/mvc-crud/Error/index

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

Imagen de como estan organizadas las carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: buenas @Luis Cifuentes. Recuerda poner el codigo como texto en lugar de imagenes, para que la gente pueda utilizarlo y ayudarte mejor.esa linea. Puedes mostrar el contenido del archivo `config/parameters.php`?

Comment: @Jakala Gracias por comentar!,ya agregue el parameters

Comment: Con lo fácil que es poner el código como texto, pones un edit con un fragmento pequeño y el resto como imagen :( :( :(

Comment: @Alfabravo Shuta srry , lo cambiaré!(Mala costumbre :/)

Comment: En la consola del navegador te salen errores?

Comment: @Alfabravo Ningun error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que haces el rewrite pero no pones las excepciones correspondientes así que el htaccess intenta buscar los estilos dentro del rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
```

Este es mi archivo y me funciona, si no te resulta la linea anterior prueba con esto:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -indexes 
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 # Activar RewriteEngine 
 RewriteEngine on 
  
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  
 RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
  
 #RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA] 
  
 #RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA] 
  
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/(.*?)$ index.php/?page=$1&action=$2&support0=$3&support1=$4 [QSA] 
  
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/(.*?)$ index.php/?page=$1&action=$2&support0=$3 [QSA] 
  
 RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/(.*?)$ index.php/?page=$1&action=$2 [QSA] 
  
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php/?page=$1 [QSA] 
  
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Hola hevejero ! Gracias por comentar! , solo tendría que agregar esta linea de codigo ? o tengo que eliminar una linea de codigo ?,por ejemplo :
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 , srry si es novato esta pregunta ,desconozco de configuraciones .htaccess, y si es posible me podrías explicar la linea de codigo que me indicaste? Se agradeceria mucho!, en caso de que no, no pasa nada muchas gracias!!

Comment: No te preocupes, trabajar con htaccess es siempre complicado xD. Primero prueba agregando esa línea sin modificar nada y después prueba con lo que voy a agregar ahora.

Comment: Hola amigo! Lo produje pero no sucede nada tampoco, al inspeccionar el header por el navegador me indica :  http://localhost/mvc-crud/usuario/assets/css/styles.css

Comment: Pero si intento en el controlador por default(Vista por default) me lleva bien : localhost/mvc-crud/assets/css/styles.css

Comment: En ese caso creo que debe ser un error muy rebuscado (alguna pequeña línea te debe causar el error) , lo que puedes hacer es usar un link absoluto: http://localhost/pagina/asset/css/style.css (agregando el http://) así siempre cargará el link sin generar uno dinámica mente. Si no quieres modificar cada página cuando lo subas al servidor puedes guardar el link en una variable de session o por js así cuando lo subas al servidor te muestra el link completo en todos los url. <?= $_SESSION['host'] ?>'assets/css/style.css

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo hejevero , ya lo solucione , era algo simple la verdad xD , simplemente al llamar al css :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url ?>assets/css/styles.css"> tenía que cambiarle el <?php base_url ?> por <?= base_url ?> y listo xD

Comment: Ah dale, que bueno que encontraste el problema xD, disculpame que esa parte del código no la había visto.